# Azure App Service tokens lost after service stops

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

My understanding: In an Azure App Service, you can set the service to basically never "fall asleep" by setting the "[Always On](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/)" setting in Azure Portal.

While this is an easy change to the service, I am trying to avoid having the service constantly run when not in use, and driving up the monthly expense of hosting the service.

My dilemma is that I have an Azure App Service running, which I authenticate a Xamarin Forms app against. In the process of logging in, I return an OAuth token to the client which is set to expire in 15 days (something long for testing).

Everything works fine while the Azure Service is running, but if the Azure Service "falls asleep" then I am forced to login again - which leads me to believe that the tokens issued by the service have been lost after the service falls asleep.

My question is: Is there a way to store the current tokens in an Azure Table Storage (or something) prior to "falling asleep", then pull from the same storage when the service "wakes up"??

I did find the below question, but couldn't get a clear understanding of how to persist the bearer tokens:
[How are bearer tokens stored server-side in Web API 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102252/how-are-bearer-tokens-stored-server-side-in-web-api-2)

I have been searching high and low with clear indication of how to do this, let alone if this is even possible.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, is this your scenario, you are building a custom authenticate  mechanism, which will provide the access token for your clients, and your clients will leverage this token to access for API in service? And now you want to store the token in Table Storage?

Comment: Hi Gary - yes, but not for a specific user, but for all valid (not expired) tokens. As an example (using a traditional asp.net website), you can use the global.asax to do certain activities on Application_Start/Application_Stop. I would like to persist the tokens before the App Service sleeps (do to no requests), but when it wakes up I would like to load in the persisted tokens back in as to not require the following:
- force users to log back into the mobile app
- not set the Azure App Service to "Always On"

Unless you feel there may be a better approach than using Azure Table Storage.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of [How are bearer tokens stored server-side in Web API 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102252/how-are-bearer-tokens-stored-server-side-in-web-api-2) you find is right. Usually, we will store the access token in client side. You can store it any place in your clients, local storage, sqlite, even files. Just to make sure, your application can get back the access token.

When your application send HTTP requests to the protected server, you will set the access token in `Authorization` header.

And your server once get a HTTP request, it will verify the token and authorize the user.